# Disable extension less URLs in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, friendly-url

I installed the Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Core NuGet package on my website and added the appropriate code in Global.asax in order to enable extension less URLs. I have now uninstalled the package, commented the corresponding code and built the solution again, however ASP.NET still redirects all the aspx pages to its extension less counterparts and throws a 404 error. Please let me know how to disable this behavior completely

Comment: Did you check your redirect url's links? maybe there are missing '.aspx' or check global asax and erase invoke of routeconfig class.

Comment: did you add RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); on application_start?

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla My links have '.aspx' and I did erase the invoke of routeconfig class in application_start

Comment: @brykneval I did add it and I commented it out when I uninstalled the NuGet

Comment: You built the solution again, but did you redeploy to the server?

Comment: @mason I am running it locally actually.

Comment: @R.S.K Have you tried rebooting your local machine then?

Comment: @mason ok, that worked.Thanks. Is it because there were some settings in my cache or machine or IIS that were not being rewritten?

Comment: @R.S.K That's my guess, but you'd probably need to experiment further if you want to know for sure. I suspect you're not that interested now that it works though...